# Que debo usar para normalizar los estilos en css

Tags: html, css3

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Estoy usando esos códigos para resetear los estilos del navegador, hace poco vi un tutorial en donde se indica que es mejor usar [normalize-css](/questions/tagged/normalize-css).

Mi pregunta es cual de los 2 deberia usar vi los estilos del normalize y no tiene la propiedad box-sizing que a lo largo genera problemas con los estilos, soy algo nuevo en esto del diseño web espero que alguien con conocimientos me pueda ayudar

Comment: A que te refieres con resetear los estilos del navegador?

Comment: No te recomiendo utilizar ningún reset en CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Resetear y normalizar son 2 opciones diferentes, el uso de una o ambas depende de tu objetivo.

Tal como lo mencionas, resetear CSS (*reset css*) tiene como objetivo eliminar todo el estilo del navegador trae por defecto. Tu ejemplo cumple con el objetivo en parte. Yo recomendaría tomar como base el [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) propuesto por Eric Meyer.

Normalizar CSS tiene como objetivo hacer más consistente los estilos por defecto entre navegador, no necesariamente reseteándolos.

Comment: SI quiero resetear en el reset css que me estas pasando como podria colocar la linea del box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: Si, la idea es que lo puedas copiar, tomar como base y añadir o modificar lo que necesites.